# Linux Debian apt-get update ERROR / Atom missing GPG key

Tags: linux, debian, atom-editor, public-key-encryption, gpg-signature

I'm running linux debian 9.4.0 64-bit on my machine. Since I installed atom text editor, I receive an ERROR while running ap-get update. The error reads the following:

> W: GPG-Fehler: https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease: Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY 4C6E74D6C0A35108
>   W: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease' is not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

The first line says that the signature of my PGP key could not be verified, since a PUBKEY is unavailable.

The same error message continously shows, even though I purged atom from my system.

Can someone lend me a hand with making my system being updating properly again and how to install atom without causing future problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I initially misunderstood the question and thought you wanted to completely remove Atom and the repository. In that case, the solution would be to remove the relevant entry from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (or the relevant file in `etc/apt/sources.list.d`, whichever exists).

Now I understand you are trying to install und update Atom without apt giving you the error message described in your question.

In that case, it seems the repository key may not be installed on your system. You can try to follow the instructions at https://packagecloud.io/app/AtomEditor/atom/gpg#gpg-apt to manually install the required GPG key. I recommend reading all the instructions on that page, but the relevant command would be `curl -L https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: My sources.list file contains no links to an Atom package.Yet, their is an atom.list file in sources.list.d with the following content: deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
Shall I empty the content of the file or delete it?

Comment: If you have no intention of installing Atom again, you can safely delete the `atom.list` file, and your problem should be solved :)

Comment: Of course I want to install atom without causing future problems again. Why should this be a problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted to get rid of your Atom installation.

Comment: Have you tried importing the key as described here: https://packagecloud.io/app/AtomEditor/atom/gpg#gpg-apt

Comment: Thank you ptschak for the link. Worked out fine for me!